# Formatting data with html before posting with php

Tags: php, html

I would like to format data with html then post it to the database as formatted, So that when i render the data in a textarea, it should appear as

**component x%**
 (Rsd = 3% ; n = 2)

Instead, in the database its posted as `<strong>`component x%`</strong><br />` (Rsd = 3% ; n = 2) and rendered the same way in the textarea

The data i am posting is in a variable as $data=`"<strong>component x%</strong><br /> (Rsd = 3% ; n = 2)"`

Suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

textareas do not render HTML, but will only show your markup as plain text. What you are probably looking for is a [WYSIWYG editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG).

Check out [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) or [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot format data with HTML.

You can format it with Javascript or PHP, and from what you post, I understand you need something like `strip_tags`

Please read:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php